# Undoing two kinds of values in the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Help! I have a posgres table like:

```
create table events(
    event_id    bigserial primary key,
    reason text not null,
    lifecycle_id bigint not null,
...
);
```

I’ve got two kinds of values in the same column. `lifecycle_id bigint not null` is either populated with an identifier for another resource (`transaction_id`) or a randomly generated number if the `transaction_id` is not present. This number is not unique and is used as a way of connecting multiple rows. I.e: there can be several rows with the same `lifecycle_id` and we will want to query it.

Obviously this is not great because it'll inevitably lead to collusions. So I’m introducing a nullable field to the table called `transaction_id` and actually populating it. I will also start generating the future values for the lifecycle field. But this isn’t enough for me. I’d like to find a way to migrate the lifecycle field into something less “hacky”. Either a sequence or a serial field.

What would you do in my shoes to not have to maintain collision-management code?

Comment: Randomly generated number? What should be the use case for? Wouldn't it be far more appropriate to have at best a null value in that case then or (if you cannot change the column) one specific dedicated sentinel value?

Comment: Apart from I'm not really sure what you actually want to achieve. Which kind of collision? Random number vs. existing transaction id?

Comment: Migrating to a sequence to avoid collisions sounds fine to me. How big is the biggest current value, compared to max bigint?

Comment: @Aconcagua every row should have a "lifecycle_id" in order to link several rows on this column. Imagine a `select * from table where lifecycle_id = 12345` and that returns 5 rows.

Yeah, random number vs transaction id collision (and even random numbers themselves) as they're using Random().nextLong() to generate the lifecycle_id. 

What I want to end up with is a table with a nullable transaction_id column and a lifecycle_id column of auto-incremental values.

Comment: @DanGetz Unfortunately the max value is`8905212385406001975`. I was just going to create a sequence from max and be on my merry way but this kinda made it problematic.